# Divide one list into two. C

Tags: c

Given a sentence, the words which are separated by spaces. Make it into two sentences with the rule: in the first rewrite all even the order of words, and the second - odd.

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and read [ask]. Asking for homework help is ok, but you need to show what you've tried and where you are stuck. This might help you get started: [strtok()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)

Comment: We are not doing homework (for you) here.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to loop over the array and check the positions of the array for punctuation that indicates the end of a sentence and then separate the array into two there. I would suggest separating it into two using something like memcpy, it's your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `strtok()` function.